# EDMX Extension - see property based on type

Tags: entity-framework

I have created a VSIX extension in which I have extended proeprties for an EDMX file, from which my T4 files generate classes I want. All works great, but what I can't figure out how to do is to only show my properties based on their type. For example I have a new property called RegEx - in which I store a regular expression. I only want this visible in the EDMX properties when the field is a string.

Any pointers?

Thanks

Ray

Answer (score 0):

In your t4 wrap the RegEx method generation with property type check:

```
<#
    if ((property.TypeUsage.EdmType is PrimitiveType)
          && 
       ((PrimitiveType)property.TypeUsage.EdmType).PrimitiveTypeKind == PrimitiveTypeKind.String)
       {
#>
    public string RegEx {get;set;} //method text
<#              
       }
#>
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks for taking the time to read and respond, but it looks like I didn't make myself clear. I know how to do this in the T4 - but I only want the new property visible in the EDMX proeperty inspector when the type of the field is a string. The standard properties already do this - if you select a string, for example in one of the entities in the EDMX designer, you see the Max Length property in the inspector, but not if you select an integer.